# Origin of the terminology "trace operator" related to boundary-value problems for PDEs

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ho.history-overview, terminology

Important results in the theory of PDEs regarding boundary-value problems are trace and extension theorems. Since the trace operator essentially acts by restriction to the boundary of the domain, I was wondering how it got the name "trace": who came up with this name, when and why?

Comment: The trace operator restricts a function to the boundary of the domain, so one can say that it "traces the boundary of the function".

Comment: Tracing being a primitive pre-computer method of [image reproduction](http://www.hintsandthings.co.uk/workshop/tracing.htm) :-)

Comment: Not sure the historical order of terminology, but for example in do Carmo's book on curves and surfaces, the trace of a parametrised curve is it's image. One "traces" the curve in space to get the image as one might trace a picture onto a new sheet of paper. Then @CarloBeenakker comment extends that notion to tracing a function along the boundary which is itself the trace in (do Carmo's sense) of the inclusion of the boundary into the domain.

Comment: Now crossposted to History of Science and Mathematics, see https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/6603/4703